# Telegram Payment 2.0 API: How do I work around with this with answerShippingQuery and answerPreCheckoutQuery?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

With the 26th April update on Telegram introducing the Payments 2.0 feature along with other minor features, I’ve decided to build a Telegram bot that included these features. However, since this is a recent update with limited example documentation (and the syntax can take a while to digest), I was stuck implementing the Payment 2.0 feature and wanted to ask anyone who has done this (or is experienced in this verse) on a few matters:

- In answering shipping / pre-checkout queries (answerShippingQuery,
  answerPreCheckoutQuery), I understand that the API will send an
  Update with the field to the bot for it to respond properly. However,
  I am not too sure how to approach this after creating the invoice
  given the parameters and arguments and would love to understand some
  form of a “code snippet” to understand how the processes work (or do
  I have to use an asynchronous function?).

  ```py
  def command TelegramShop(update: Update, _: CallbackContext):
      user = update.message.from_user

      Product = telegram.LabeledPrice("Demostration Product", 1000)
      ShippingMethod_1 = telegram.LabeledPrice("Self Collection", 0)
      ShippingMethod_2 = telegram.LabeledPrice("Mail In Delivery", 100)
      ShippingMethod_3= telegram.LabeledPrice("Tracked Mail In Delivery", 250)
      print("Hello")
      _.bot.sendInvoice(chat_id = user.id, title = "Demostration Product", description = "This box demostration does wonders!", payload = "productpayload", provider_token = "TOKEN", currency = "USD", prices = [Product], need_phone_number = True, need_email = True, need_shipping_address = True, send_phone_number_to_provider = True, send_email_to_provider = True, is_flexible = True)
      # Unsure how to add this answering of shipping query into the Telegram Bot.
      _.bot.answerShippingQuery(shipping_query_id = "swiftboxA", ok = False, error_message = "sorry, this does not work!")
  ```
- There are numerous identifiers within Payment API 2.0 ranging from
  `shipping_query_id`, `pre_checkout_query_id` and even payment identifiers
  such as `telegram_payment_charge_id` and `provider_payment_charge_id`.
  How do I go about obtaining these identifiers and for the payment
  identifiers, is there an appropriate code snippet illustrating their
  use?

Answer (score 2):

TBH I haven't worked with payments much so far, but regarding "limited expample documentation" I would like to point you to

- a [step-by-step guide](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#step-by-step-process) in the official Telegram Bot API docs
- an [example on payments](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/paymentbot.py) provided by `python-telegram-bot`

If you have already seen these (which wasn't clear to my from your question), please just ignore my answer.

Also a side note: You should rename the second parameter from `_` to `context`. The underscore is just a convention for unused parameters, but you apparently want to use it ;)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maitainer of `python-telegram-bot`.